# differences between ubuntu touch and ubuntu-touch-preview

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, cd-image

does anyone know what the differences between ubuntu-touch and ubuntu-touch-preview are?

see their links at:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

Also, the instructions explain the use of zip files for installation but it never explains what the use of those img files are. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4):

## Ubuntu Touch

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/

**ubuntu-touch**: is the *to be* final system, the main element of this build is that it is a *flipped* image, that is an Ubuntu `boot.img` that boots straight into Ubuntu and then loads android in an `lxc` container.

The Ubuntu part of this image is build directly on cdimage and the android part aims to be as well.

## Ubuntu Touch Preview

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

This is the build that is now considered **legacy**, it is build entirely on Jenkins infrastructure and pulled into cdimage for public consumption.

This image is also the *unflipped* version, that is an Android `boot.img` that boots into Android and starts Ubuntu in a new pid namespaced chroot.

## File description

First some generic conventions:

- **[device]** can be any of `mako` (Nexus 4), `maguro` (Galaxy Nexus), `grouper` (Nexus 7 Wifi) or `manta` (Nexus 10).
- **[series]** can be any of `saucy`, `raring` or `quantal` (and any other series after `saucy`)

So given the former, this is the file description:

- `[series]-preinstalled-boot-armel+[device].img` corresponds to the boot image partition for Android devices which is the Linux kernel plus an Android ramdisk. Used in unflipped images.
- `[series]-preinstalled-boot-armhf+[device].img` corresponds to the boot image partition for Android devices which is the Linux kernel plus an Ubuntu ramdisk. Used in flipped images.
- `[series]-preinstalled-recovery-armel+[device].img` corresponds to the recovery image partition for Android devices which is a small system from where primarily update zips can be deployed. For the `saucy` timeline an Ubuntu specific way to perform updates is being setup.
- `[series]-preinstalled-system-armel+[device].img` corresponds to the system image partition for Android devices which could be simplified as the Android user space part of the OS.
- `[series]-preinstalled-armel+[device].zip` this is the update zip for unflipped images, it is basically the Android `boot.img` plus the `system.img`
- `[series]-preinstalled-touch-armel+[device].zip` this is the update zip for flipped images, it is basically the Ubuntu `boot.img` plus the `system.img`
- `[series]-preinstalled-phablet-armhf.zip` This is the Ubuntu OS itself for unflipped legacy images, it is device agnostic.
- `[series]-preinstalled-touch-armhf.zip` This is the Ubuntu OS itself for flipped images, it is device agnostic.